# I have a cell with "menutable" class ,and also a div with "gallery" class, I want to when mouse get over menutable div, gallery div is shown

Tags: css, html, hover

I have a cell with "menutable" class ,and also  a div with "gallery" class, I want to when mouse get over menutable div, gallery div is shown

```
<div class="menu">
     <table>
               <tr>
                  <td class="menutable"><a href="#">Gallery</a></td>
                  <td>...</td>
                  <td>...</td>
                  <td>...</td>  
               </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
          <div class="menuincluder">
            <div class="gallery" >
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

this is css code

```
   .menuincluder{
        position:relative;
        width:955px;
        height:340px;
        margin:auto;

    }
    .gallery{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        height:331px;
        width:946px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .menutable:hover ~ .gallery  /*this part didn't work!*/
    { 
        display:block;
        border:9px solid red;
    }
```

how could i do it?

Comment: Have you tried it with Javascript? The ~ selector is for when the two elements are siblings. This is not the case for you.

Comment: You cannot do this with pure CSS, because it would require traversal up the ancestors of `.menutable` in order to reach `.gallery`, which CSS is incapable of doing. Given your markup, it will have to be a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mouseover of the `.menu` div to show/hide the entire `.menu` block:

```
.menu+.main {
    display: none;
}
.menu:hover+.main {
    display: block;
}
```

However, as ajp15243 pointed out in the comments, you can't do it (in pure CSS) just with a mouseover of the `.menutable` table cell because CSS can't traverse *up* the DOM.

Comment: sorry you misunderstood,I don't want ".menu" to hide,I want when mouse get over ".menutable" class".gallery"was shown

Comment: I understood that. And as I said, that's not possible with pure CSS.